# Slow response of my laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 7 Home Basic.

My problem is that it's responding very slowly in every single application.

I have checked for viruses, and my Antivirus software is working fine.

I don't know what else to check.

Comment: Have you checked the CPU and disk usage to see if any of them are at a high utilization percentage?

Comment: Processes:104 CPU Usage:24% Physical Memory:65%

Comment: What a about disk usage? In Windows 7 you can view the disk usage by opening up task manager, going to the performance tab, then clicking resource monitor at the bottom of the window. Then of course select the disk tab in the resource monitor window. It's not quite as straight forward as it is in Windows 10, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: 0 KB/sec Disk I/O and 0% Higher active time

Comment: Does it respond slow when opening an application, or just when using it in general?

Comment: In general it's having slow response. But soo

Comment: But sometime it works ok.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Just 2 months before I already changed my hard disk with new one installed fresh window 7.

Comment: If your memory usage is 65% of total you are probably using lots of virtual memory (which has to be swapped back and forth with the hard drive), which really slows things down. If your installed memory is 2Gb or less, more physical memory might help. For Windows 7, I think 4GB is a minimum and 8GB is decent for most normal usage.

Comment: Thx for the help☺